# Sharing login credentials on localhost with 2 web applications on IIS7, possible?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-7, forms-authentication, single-sign-on

I have 2 asp.net web applications running in IIS7:

```
http://app1.local/
```

and

```
http://app2.local/
```

My host.ini file just maps the above urls to localhost:

```
::1 app1.local
::1 app2.local
```

I added the same machine key to both their web.config's.

**When I sign into app2, and then go to app1, the call to Request.IsAuthenticated is false?**

Should this work?

Comment: Do you have your config files setup as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx